# Can't find MongoClient in Java Drivers

Tags: java, netbeans, mongodb-java

In reading all the documentation on the mongo site for using the Java Driver, it makes references to using MongoClient() to make a connection.  It talks about how they formerly used Mongo() but it has been deprecated.  However, when I download the latest (or any) version of the java driver that the Mongo database links to (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/), and load it into my project libraries, I cannot import com.mongodb.MongoClient because it isn't there!  I've tried half a dozen different versions of the driver they link to.  I can actually make my program work just fine with the deprecated Mongo(), but I don't want to be building new software on deprecated features.  I can't find anyone else with the same problem on here either[image: Image of libraries shown in netbeans below, v 2.93 in this case]

The above is from version 2.93.  Can anyone help me find what I'm doing wrong or missing?  I would think its the driver version but these are the links right from Mongo's website.  I also don't think its usage error, as I can make everything else work just fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suggest you grab [driver version 2.11.3](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/)

The JAR contains the `MongoClient` class that you're referring to. Latter is new to the MongoDB Java driver and has only been included since version 2.10.0 (The version you are referring to is 2.9.3, as of now the latest driver version is the aforementioned 2.11.3)

Cheers ;)

Comment: On first glance, 2.9.3 seems to be the latest driver in the list, but the list is alphabetically sorted, not sorted by timestamp, so versions 2.1*.* (e.g. 2.11.3) appear right after 2.1 and already before 2.2.