# mongo-java-driver-2.9.3.jar doesnt include MongoClient

Tags: java, mongodb, classpath

I have a small java project and I would like to use mongo-java-driver in order to connect to my mongoDB .

I download the latest mongo-java-driver from MongoDB site (mongo-java-driver-2.9.3.jar)

(from here:http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.9.3/

but it seems that MongoClient isnt in the JAR file.

Any idea?

Comment: Where do you download it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer here: [Can't find MongoClient in Java Drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497799/cant-find-mongoclient-in-java-drivers).
Indeed it's in the 2.11.3 jar but not in 2.9.3.

Comment: The latest is 2.11.3 not 2.9.3